# Best way to output n digital signals using n-1 DAC channels

Tags: analog, audio, dac, dsp, digital-audio

I have 3 digital signals that need to be mixed and output into the analog domain. My DAC has 2 channels (Left and Right).

The way I see it, I can:

1. mix the signals 1, 2, and 3 digitally and output them on L AND R - mixing the two signals in analog.
2. output signal 1 on L, signals 2 and 3 on R, and then mix them proportionally in analog.
3. mix the signals 1, 2, and 3 digitally, and output them on L and ignore the R channel.

As I understand it, in the first case each signal will be divided by 3 in order to mix, so my 16bit signals (65,536 possible levels) are now limited to 21,845.333 33 possible levels - which would be just shy of a full 15bit signal.

In the second case, one signal is output at full 16bit level, while the other two are halved - so 15bit and 15bit

So it seems like the second case is better with it's average of 15.33bits compared with the first case's less than 15bits per signal. But in the first case the signal is duplicated and mixed in analog, which maybe adds more quality to the output? On the other hand by adding the two signals in the analog domain, I'm also adding the noise from both DACs together which is probably bad.

What is the right way to think about this problem? is it better to mix in analog or digital? Does outputting the signal twice and mixing in analog help make up for lost bits?

I know if there is any phase difference between channels on my DAC then the first plan doesn't work -  the datasheet claims both channels are in phase but I plan to test that if the first plan is better.

Edit: the goal is to output three (or more) audio signals on two dac channels.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? To output 3 sound signals on 2 audio outputs? Or to communicate 3 values to annother device (which one)?

Comment: First case: Mixing 3 signals does not require dividing by 3. In audio, for example, 3 violins are louder then a single violin, so dividing by 3 and then mixing (which results in 1 again) makes no sense. That's handled by doing the addition in a wider variable (32 bit, for example) so you have all the dynamic range, and then clip when converting back to 16-bit, for example.

Comment: That's all assuming your analog mixing / demodulating process has better than 98dB SNR, otherwise you won't recover 16-bit data. Anything you do in analog just adds noise and distortion. Uncorrelated noise always adds. Every 6dB of SNR effectively costs one bit of resolution. What is preventing you from adding another DAC?

Comment: @Sandro updated - goal is three audio signals on two channels

Comment: @Unimportant i’d like to avoid clipping. The three audio signals are synthesized (so use the full bit range available) and musical, so the signals will always clip unless they’re playing the same note at a phase offset.

Comment: Mix (digitally) all 3 down to 2 channels, allowing you to pan each input anywhere you want between the 2 channels.

Comment: If you mix them digitally, then scale back to 16 bit with dithering, you'll keep most of the bits...